# Namespace issue while adding new component to Mule flow

Tags: java, namespaces, mule, mule-studio

I'm new to Mule, Whenever i'm adding 'Poll' with fixed-frequency scheduler to mule flow, getting namespace error.Shouldn't mule keep adding the namespace whenever we add new component to flow through editor ? Do i have explicitly add the namespace related with 'poll'? I was expecting namespace for poll to be available in Mule core. I'm using Mule studio-3.5.0.

> Invalid content was found starting with element
>   'fixed-frequency-scheduler'

Here is the mule configuration -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
  version="EE-3.4.1"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/3.4/mule-jersey.xsd
  http://jersey.apache.org/core http://jersey.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd">


<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="mule-configFlow" doc:name="mule-configFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8095" path="myapp/v1/ping" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </poll>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mytest" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>
```

Edit:
As suggested by David, i'm trying to add, Mule 3.5.0 Runtime by following [Mule documentations](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime) but i'm not finding either 3.5.0 Cascade or BigHorn.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixed-frequency-scheduler` is in Mule core but of Mule 3.5.0 Cascade or BigHorn, not 3.4.1 EE as you're using currently.

Switch to one of these 2 runtimes and it will work.

Comment: I'm unable to add 3.5.0 Runtime, does it come along with Mule Studio 3.5.0, by default it has 3.4.1 and don't see it available softwares. I've updated the question with my findings.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was certain that 3.5 runtimes were available in Studio 3.5. It shows I'm not a Studio user :) 3.5 is available in CloudHub for sure but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Or you could build Andes from source https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.5.0-andes ...